# pass value into jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I would like to pass a value into a jquery dialog.  For several reasons the page is in iFrames.  The process starts with firing this function from a page within an iframe:

```
<Tr onclick="fireOpen1(true,myValue)">
```

here is the function (within the iframe page):

```
function fireOpen1(redirect,theValue) {
//here are two of the ways I have tried tp pass the value, neither work
parent.document.getElementById('theID').value = theValue;
parent.document.theForm('theID').value = theValue;
parent.openDialog1();
if (redirect) {
   //do a redirect of the parent here
     window.location.href = "left.asp";
}
}
```

which calls the opener on the parent page:

```
function openDialog1() { // called by the inner iframe
$('#dialog1').dialog({
show: "fold",
hide: "explode",
width: 600,
height: 200,
buttons: {
    Close: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
});
}
```

and here is my div  with the contents of the dialog:

```
<div id="dialog1" > 
   <form name="theForm" action="frames.asp" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="theID" value="0">
</form>
 the id is <%= request.form("theID") %> ...
</div>
```

The dialog shows no problem but my value is not available.  How can I pass this value.  My reason for using this method is because I wanted to detach the dialog from the opener so its can remain there when the opener redirects.   Thanking you

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the **id** in `input field`

```
<input type="hidden" name="theID" value="0">
```

should be

```
<input type="hidden" name="theID" id="theID" value="0">
```

Comment: Yes that did it.  Thank you for your time and advice, very much appreciated indeed.  You have a fine day...

Comment: I thought it worked.....im a bit confused, its now not working.  How would you write the value to the dialog inside the div?  Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `parent.$('#dialog1').data('v', myValue);` just before `parent.openDialog1();` and then access it in dialog `open event` as such `var v = $('#dialog1').data('v');`

Comment: I get I get object doesnt support this property or method  when I put parent.$('#dialog1').data('v', 'aValue') just before parent.openDialog1() and I get expected identifier, string  or number when I put var v = $('#dialog1').data('v') in the open event.  I have posted a reply to show you how I have used them.